# How to filter IP addresses by route in bottle?

Tags: python, bottle

My `bottle` webserver provides several services (routes). Some of them must be restricted to private ([RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)) IPs, while others serve both private and public ones.

Right now I check at the beginning of the routes

```
if IPy.IP(bottle.request.remote_addr).iptype() == 'PRIVATE':
    # code for private service
```

I need to check this for each route restricted to private IPs (10 cases and growing) and do not need to do that for the private and public ones (1 case).

**Is there a global filter for routes where I could add this decision tree?**

I am specifically looking for a way to to that in the python application, and not through e.g. an upstream filtering reverse proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything built in, but you could use a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) to do that. Return a wrapper from the decorator, which performs the check for the IP type and returns the regular view if the check passes or an error-message (or similar) otherwise.
The following should work:

```
def private_only(route):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if IPy.IP(bottle.request.remote_addr).iptype() == 'PRIVATE':
            return route(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return "Not allowed!"
    return wrapper
```

Then decorate your private views with it:

```
@route('/my/internal/route')
@private_only
def internal_view():
    return some_data()
```