# IP filtering in bottle

Tags: python, routes, ip, filtering, bottle

I have a Bottle app on heroku, and I need to filter inbound IP addresses. I don't have much idea how to do this.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496819/how-to-filter-ip-addresses-by-route-in-bottle) suggests using a wrapper, but this is for private routes - not filtering inbound requests. The wrapper is:

```
def private_only(route):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if IPy.IP(bottle.request.remote_addr).iptype() == 'PRIVATE':
            return route(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return "Not allowed!"
    return wrapper
```

Would changing the wrapper to:

```
def private_only(route):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if IPy.IP(bottle.request.remote_addr).iptype() in ALLOWED_IPS:
            return route(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return "Not allowed!"
    return wrapper
```

and decorating routes with:

```
@route('/my/internal/route')
@private_only
def my_view():
    return some_data()
```

work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enable filtering for the entire bottle application, I suggest to create a plugin instead. The example below should work:

```
from bottle import request
from bottle import HTTPError
from bottle import app

class IPFilteringPlugin(object):
    name = 'ipfiltering'
    api = 2

    def __init__(self, allowed_ips=[]):
        self.allowed_ips = allowed_ips

    def apply(self, callback, route):
        def wrapper(*a, **ka):
            if request.remote_addr in self.allowed_ips:
                return callback(*a, **ka)
            raise HTTPError("Permission denied", status=403) 
        return wrapper

app.install(IPFilteringPlugin(["127.0.0.1", "10.0.2.15"])
```

Note as well that you can use this plugin only per route, by specifying it in the `@route` definition

```
filter_internal = IPFilteringPlugin(["127.0.0.1", "10.0.2.15"])
@route('/my/internal/route', apply=filter_internal)
def internal_route(self):
    pass

# or directly route per route
@route('/my/internal/route', apply=IPFilteringPlugin(["127.0.0.1", "10.0.2.15")
def internal_route(self):
    pass
```

Comment: Great suggestion. I changed `raise HTTPError("Permission denied", status=403)` to `raise abort(403, "Access denied")`. To overcome Python trying to do ErrorHandling on the HTTPError but that might be due to my specific configuration.